# add custom header to authenticatio url & get image javascript

Tags: javascript, http, header, marker

I am in heady trouble with http header basic authentication in javascript. I want to add custom marker on google map. To get marker image i have to basic authenticate the url. Below way i am trying:

```
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

            icon: "shewa:123456@http://104.198.52.90:8080/gps71/images 
            /marker/ninad_marker.png"

          });
```